# How to run caja without terminal?

Tags: applications, file-management

I installed caja because "Files" is not working so well and I might file a bug.  But I also like its image reducer plugin.  I installed it, but it does not show up in the app finder.  I can launch it via terminal.  How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a .desktop file and put it inside `~/.local/share/applications`.

To do that open any text editor and modify the following code to make it work with your app. Please modify the `Exec=` line with the correct command to launch the app. You can add an icon as well, for that you need to save the file somewhere and add the full path.

Save the following as caja.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name='Caja File Manager'
Comment='Open the file explorer'
Exec='caja'  
Icon=''
```

Comment: works.. but I should file an issue with caja.  Most other programs install properly